# Access spring property in jsp or javascript

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a pageSize variable configured in spring properties. I need to access this pageSize property in almost all the jsps. What is the best way to get hold of this spring property.

src\main\resources\web.properties contains default.page.items.size=10

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:web.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:core.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

I know how to access the property in the controller but as this property is been accessed my mutliple pages hence i want some way to access it javascript or jsp directly

Comment: What do you mean by _spring properties_?

Comment: spring mvc resource properties

Comment: take a look at Spring MVC internaization http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: Sotirios: updated the post

Answer (score 1):

I used this in a old project (not sure if still works) in your dispatcher context declare a bean like:

```
<bean id="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
               <list>
                     <value>classpath:web.properties</value>
                     <value>classpath:core.properties</value>
                </list>
         </property>
</bean>
```

and then, if using standard JSTL view resolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="order" value="2"></property>
          <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
          <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
               <list>
                     <value>myProps</value>
               </list>
          </property>
</bean>
```

You should be able to access the properties inside JSP using `${myProps.XXX}`

Comment: The above solution didnt work for me as I am using UrlBasedViewResolver